# Error on installing ASP.NET Identity 2 Samples

Tags: nuget, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to install ASP.NET Identity 2 samples project. I open Visual Studio 2013, create an empty ASP.NET project, open Package Manager Console and type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

After some time of installing it returns an error:

```
Unable to uninstall 'jQuery 1.10.2' because 'bootstrap 3.0.0' depends on it.
```

Ok, I type the installation command again. This time the error is:

```
Failed to add reference to 'System.Net.Http'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

All subsequent attempts to install finish up with the same error.

**UPD:** I have installed the samples successfully using "Manage NuGet Packages" UI. Still interested why it have not worked in console? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I've encountered exactly the same problem. Can you expand on your comment about resolving the problem with the NuGet UI?

Comment: Right click on a project -> Manage NuGet Packages... -> Select "Include Prerelease" instead of "Stable Only" at the top drop-down -> Type "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples" in the search box -> Select "Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples" -> Click "Install"

Comment: Way too simple :) never even occurred to me. Thanks. Actually I suspect that there may be no difference in the two methods, just a reward for persistence. I've installed them successfully from the command line but it has required multiple attempts.